# How to use GitX to cherry-pick a commit from master to another branch?

Tags: cherry-pick, gitx

(Note:  I do know how to do this using the command line git client; this question is on behalf of a command-line-phobic co-worker who I am introducing to git via the GitX GUI application on his Mac)

I see that in GitX you can right-click on a commit in the commits-list and choose "Cherry pick commit into master"; but what I want to be able to do is the opposite:  cherry-pick a commit from master into a (non-master) branch.

Is there a way to do this inside of GitX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matthias Leppich on the rowanj/gitx mailing list (atn github.com) sent me the answer to this question, so I'm quoting it here for the record:

> @jfriesne you can 'cherry-pick' commits to your currently checked out
>   branch. If you like to pick commits from *master* to *another* branch, you
>   just need to checkout *another* branch before picking.